# How to design these sqlite tables with delete and update cascade

Tags: sqlite

I tried to do this:

`Recipe` table with RecipeID (Primary Key and Foreigh Key) and RecipeName (unique).
`Ingredient` table with IngredientID (Primay and Foreign Key) and IngredientName (Unique).
`RecipeDetail` table with RecipeID, IngredientID and IngredientNme.

- If user deletes an Ingredient from the Ingredient Table, all records in the RecipeDetail with this IngredientId must be deleted.
- If user deletes a Recipe from Recipe Table, all records in RecipeDetail with this RecipeId must be deleted.

Any clue? Thanks

Comment: U have to Tag the platform in which u are implementing your program. Is it Android or JAVA ???

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid: The platform should not be relevant for this question, this can be solved using constraints.

Comment: @PeterLang: _Depends_ on the target Android version. In anything prior to Android 2.2 foreign keys had to be implemented either using triggers or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) explains how to create Constraints between your tables. To force deletion of orphaned records, use [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions).

Also make sure, that foreign key support [is enabled.](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)

---

Your create-script could look like this

```
CREATE TABLE RecipeDetail(
  RecipeID      INTEGER REFERENCES Recipe(RecipeID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  IngredientID  INTEGER REFERENCES Ingredient(IngredientID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (RecipeID, IngredientID)
);
```

The primary key makes sure that no ingredient is assigned to a recipe twice. `IngredientName` should not be stored in the intersection table, this leads to redundant data.

Comment: I think I tried this, If I delete the RecipeID from the Recipe Table, Yes, The RecipeDetail rows related to RecipeID will be delted. BUT IF I Deleted the IngredientID from the Ingredient Table, Only the row with IngridientID at RecipeDetail Table will be deleted, Not the Entire ROWS.

Comment: The Condition should be if either IngridientID at Ingredient table or RecipeID at Recipe Table is deleted, All Rows in RecipeDetails Table related with the Ingredient ID and RecipeId MUST BE DELETED.